# How can I simulate app being killed in background?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I'm trying to verify that my app (App1) behaves correctly when it is shut down by the system after it launches another app (App2). Is there any way to simulate or force this behavior?

Telling the simulator to simulate a memory warning while App2 is running doesn't do anything until App1 is brought back to the foreground. Would killing App1 from the debugger simulate the same sequence of app events?

EDIT: My app is placed in the background when it launches a second app to handle a file. This second app then relaunches my app, and I'm trying to verify that my app behaves correctly when the system has shut it down while the second app is executing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, if your app is in the background already. An app killed by the system while in the background is terminated with no warning-- no app delegate methods are called, no state changes are made-- which is exactly what happens when you do a debugger stop while the app is in the background. (This presupposes that you've already put your app in the background by clicking the home button on the simulator or Cmd-Shift-H)

(As @Inafziger notes, you can also get the same effect by using the simulator's interface to force quit the running app.)

Comment: Just a quick question, do you mean debugger "Pause" as opposed to "Stop"? I could not find a way to "Stop" debugger.  I would really like to know since I am debuggin a background location app and want to see it relaunched after system kill.

Comment: @JitendraKulkarni: I mean Stop. It's the big button at top-left in the Xcode toolbar, next to the Run (looks like a "Play") button. It simply terminates the process, whatever state it's in. Which is traditionally what happens to a backgrounded iOS app when it gets killed by the system.

Answer (score 40):

### iOS 14.5 and Later

Enable **Settings** - **Developer** - **Fast App Termination** on the device:

> [image: screenshot of Settings - Developer - Fast App Termination]

This will terminate, instead of suspend, your app when they're backgrounded. This is useful primarily for testing state restoration logic.

---

### iOS 14.4 and Earlier

As the other answers note, you can immediately end your app by force-quitting it or by stopping the debugger.  Your app will get no warning in those cases.

If you're looking to test your `applicationWillTerminate` methods, set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES` in your .plist and then switch apps or press the home button.  Make sure you set the key to a Boolean, not the string "YES".

Comment: This is a *very* useful answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I've been seeing `applicationWillTerminate` also called when the user force-quits an app in recent iOS versions.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is a couple of years old, but wanted to share if anyone else is looking into this now. Try the following steps:

1. Run the app on a device
2. Press the home button once to go to the home screen
3. Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds until you see the power off slider
4. Press and hold the home button for 5 seconds

If you were running the app from Xcode you should see `Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9`

Comment: How can I do this on a iPhone X?

Comment: Thanks! The easiest way I found so far. I'm using an Iphone 7 to test.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to:

- Tap the home button, to take you to the home screen
- Tap the home button twice (use the keyboard shortcut in the simulator)
- Touch and hold the icon at the bottom until it starts to wiggle
- Tap the dash circle `-` to remove it from memory

This gives you the app delegate methods of going into the background, etc. This is how it works in iOS 6 and below.

Comment: Minor correction - the icon has a dash, not an X. The X appears when deleting an app.