# How can I simulate app being killed by the OS in background?

Tags: ios, xcode

my iOS app behave weirdly when I reopen it after a long time (few hours). I bet the problem happen when the app is purged from memory by the OS. In such cases I need to kill and reopen the app. I'm struggling to test this scenario, is there a way to put in background an app and simulate OS purging on the real device?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969396/how-can-i-simulate-app-being-killed-in-background) suggest to kill the app while in background, but it's a different scenario, in such case it's always working OK.

Thanks

Comment: You have tried [all these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14969438/7347933)?

Comment: that's equivalent to kill the app, it's not what I'm looking for

Comment: First, confirm that your app ***IS*** being purged from memory. If your app loads fine after explicitly "killing" it, but "behaves weirdly" when you don't, then it is highly unlikely that the OS is actually purging it.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to check if the app is purged from memory?